# TYPO3, select from localized table

Tags: localization, typo3

I just created a localized table. When adding translations they go into the table with a new uid. I have checked with other localized extension, so this seems to be right.

Example: Localized entries in a table gives not just translations but also extra entries in the table with new uid

- Tysk (uid 1, Danish and default language)
- -- German (uid 7, English translation of "Tysk")
- -- Deutch (uid 13, German translation of "Tysk")

Now I have a concern:

When tre persons from Denmark, England and Germany all sign up for something in German, they will sign up for uid 1, uid 7 and uid 13... I would prefer if they all signed up for the default language.

Else it will be difficult to generate a list of users that signed up for a language if each language will exist with own uid for each translation.

What have I missed? Som exec_select_localized function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 100% correct that every translation is a new record (= new uid) in the same table. So you have done everything right.

For the frontend you can use
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getRecordOverlay('tx_mytable', array('uid' => 1));
with the original record (with the result of a record in exec_SELECTquery()),

or in the TYPO3 Backend look at

BackendUtility::getRecordLocalization('tx_mytable', 4)

to get the localized record.

Comment: thanks. I create a dropdown to choose language from. I keep the uid for the default language and just translate the title so no one sign up for a localized copy but allways the default language. it works fine. thanks.